# Automatically use blue color for comments in input cell

Tags: notebooks, color, stylesheet, format, comment

Currently, when I type comments into input cell the comment has the same color or style as the function color/style as shown in figure number 1.

I would like to automatically use blue color for my comment in input cell as illustrated in figure number 2.

Could anyone tell me how to do that?

[Here](https://ufile.io/99nn9) is the stylesheet I used. I got it from the course below:
http://www.physics.umd.edu/courses/CourseWare/EssentialMathematica/

Now, I am using *Mathematica* Student Edition version 10.4.0.0.
[image]

Comment: (1) Each notebook appears to have a *private* stylesheet (I checked only two), so you'll have to reset the stylesheet. (2) There is no syntax coloring in input cells at all.  If someone knows how it is turned on/off, they might be able to answer.

Comment: @MichaelE2 "There is no syntax coloring in input cells at all." - This statement is not true, obviously. The syntax coloring is controlled by the `ShowAutoStyles` option.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov There is no syntax coloring at all on my machine, then (V11.2, MacOS).  Everything is a nice, bold, black in the input cells of the notebooks obtained from the site linked by the OP. It's "obvious" :) -- http://i.stack.imgur.com/drFYJ.png -- Also, I had already checked `ShowAutoStyles`, which is set to `True` according to the Options Inspector, so that is not (the only thing) controlling the styling in these notebooks.  Also, the comment color is supposed to be non-black color I can't describe, again according to the Options Inspector.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I meant *in general* there is syntax coloring in *Mathematica*.  That old notebook is quite strange, need to investigate why it switches off the syntax coloring. I suppose that some old (and unsupported) options interfere with new settings in an unexpected way...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using an ancient stylesheet, that doesn't take advantage of stylesheet inheritance. In particular, it doesn't inherit from the default/core stylesheet where autostyles are controlled. You can fix autostyles by inheriting the default stylesheet. You can use `Format | Edit Stylesheet...` from the menu and edit the stylesheet used by your notebook by adding the cell `Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]]` at the top. Or, you can open the stylesheet notebook itself and add that cell, at the top.

A programmatic method, given the file location of the stylesheet, is to use:

```
NotebookSave @ NotebookWrite[
    NotebookOpen@file,
    Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions->"Default.nb"]]
]
```

Comment: Thanks. I like that ancient stylesheet but I do not have ability to create my own now. Where to put that code above? I tried evaluating that code in the notebook but the input cell now is similar to default.

Comment: What does `Options[EvaluationNotebook[], StyleDefinitions]` return? If it isn't something like `{StyleDefinitions -> Notebook[{Cell[..], ...}, ...]}` then you need to go to select `Format | Edit Stylesheet..` from the menu, and then go back to the notebook and make sure the `Options` call above returns the desired `StyleDefinitions` output.

Comment: This is what I get by evaluating that command `{StyleDefinitions->FrontEnd`FileName[{$RootDirectory,C:,Users,Administrator,Desktop,Mathematica,EssentialMathematicaArchive},TutorialJJK.nb,CharacterEncoding->UTF-8]} `

Comment: @anhnha If you can get the file location (as indicated in your message above), then you can use NotebookSave/NotebookWrite/NotebookOpen to add the inherited stylesheet.

Comment: Can you be a little bit more specific? How to do that? I am completely new to stylesheet.

Comment: Try `file = FileNameJoin[{$RootDirectory, "C:", "Users", "Administrator", "Desktop", "Mathematica", "EssentialMathematicaArchive", "TutorialJJK.nb"}]` and see if `NotebookOpen[file]` works. If it doesn't work, you will need to find the file yourself. Once you find the file location, you can use the NotebookSave approach in my answer.

Comment: I tried the above and I can open it and used programmatic method. However, the stylesheet seems to switch to similar to default one. The input cell is as default.

Comment: Well, it somehow works! But there is a problem with the color and font. Where can I change the color and font of input cell? The commment is gray now.

Comment: Can't you use the preferences menu as in the other answers?

Comment: yes, it works but only color. I don't see anywhere in preferences to change the font.

Comment: Sounds like you should ask a new question about how to customize AutoStyleOptions.

Comment: I can do it now. I will wait some time before giving the bounty. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this by modifying `AutoStyleOptions` programmatically:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 AutoStyleOptions -> {"CommentStyle" -> {FontWeight -> Bold,
     FontColor -> Blue, ShowAutoStyles -> False, ShowSyntaxStyles -> False, 
     AutoNumberFormatting -> False}}]
```

Comment: Could you tell me where to add this code?

Comment: @BlueSky You should simply evaluate this in the Notebook where you wish to change the formatting of comments. If you wish to make this default formatting, just replace `EvaluationNotebook[]` with `$FrontEnd`.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to evaluate that but it doesn't work. Maybe my stylesheet overdrives this and do not allow me to change.

Comment: I am using stylesheet from the course below. Hope you could help me out.
http://www.physics.umd.edu/courses/CourseWare/EssentialMathematica/

Comment: @BlueSky In the "TutorialJJK.nb" stylesheet I haven't found the `AutoStyleOptions`, so probably there is another reason. Note that the stylesheet is very old, it is created with version 4.0, hence it potentially can contain some obsolete options which can produce unexpected results in new versions.

Comment: Thank you. Hope someone can figure out where the problem is because I like that stylesheet very much. I can't create my own stylesheet myself now - just a beginer.

Comment: @BlueSky I recommend you to ask the official tech support for the help.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to contact. However, to get help from school may take a long time.

Answer (score 6):

While you can do this via a stylesheet, and also programmatically, the quickest way to do it is via the preferences menu:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and this works. But the problem is that it only work with default stylesheet. However, I am using a stylesheet from other and it doesn't work when I load this stylesheet. Could you tell me how to make it work with the stylesheet?

Comment: @BlueSky Probably your custom stylesheet has the `AutoStyleOptions` option set for the `"Input"` style, and this option overrides the global option. Please check this: open the stylesheet, find the `"Input"` style, select the cell and press Shift+Ctrl+E.

Comment: I am using stylesheet from the course below. Hope you could help me out. http://www.physics.umd.edu/courses/CourseWare/EssentialMathematica/

Comment: I have just check it and get this for input cell: 

Cell[StyleData["Input"],
 CellFrame->0.5,
 CellMargins->{{25, 10}, {8, 8}},
 Evaluatable->True,
 CellGroupingRules->"InputGrouping",
 CellHorizontalScrolling->True,
 PageBreakWithin->False,
 GroupPageBreakWithin->False,
 CellLabelMargins->{{5, Inherited}, {Inherited, Inherited}},
 DefaultFormatType->DefaultInputFormatType,
 FormatType->InputForm,
 ShowStringCharacters->True,
 NumberMarks->True,
 CounterIncrements->"Input",
 FontSize->18,
 FontWeight->"Bold",
 Background->RGBColor[1, 0.700008, 0.4]]

Comment: @BlueSky you can add the `AutoStyleOptions` that Alexey shows in his answer to the `Input` style for your stylesheet. In comments to Alexey's answer it appears the stylesheet is very old. Maybe you are using an old version of Mathematica too. Can you please update your question with the version number you are using.

Comment: Thank you. I am using 10.4 student edition version. I will try that option now. Should I update?

Comment: Alexey's answers should work fine in 10.4

Comment: Thanks. I tried that answer but it doesn't work in my stylesheet.

Answer (score 4):

You will find this in the *Preferences* (or *Settings*) for Mathematica; follow the tabs in the Preferences window:

> Appearance > Syntax Coloring > Other

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and this works. But the problem is that it only work with default stylesheet. However, I am using a stylesheet from other and it doesn't work when I load this stylesheet. Could you tell me how to make it work with the stylesheet?